# Kotlin - IntelliJ cannot resolve the reference (from synthetic class)

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlinc

I am using Kotlin and I have the kotlinc compiler plugin (using arrow-meta library) in place which changes the .class by adding for example new properties or new method etc during kotlin compilation time. for example, the original source Kotlin A.kt is like below

```
@MetaData
data class A (val x: String, val y: String)
```

after applying compiler plugin, the .class will be altered to (from source perspective), basically I will add implicitly MetaData into the primary constructor for all class so long as it is with annonation **@MetaData** in place, plus a new method `fun getMetaData()`  generated

```
    data class A(val x: String, val y:String, val myMeta: MetaData) {
       fun getMetaData() {
         //some logic check
         return myMeta
       }
    }
```

now when it comes to use the new synthetic "class" manipulated as below, IntelliJ complains it cannot find resolve A (it has only the constructor with 2 parameters not 3) and cannot resolve the the synthetic method getMetaData() either.

```
val x = A("ba", "fo", MetaData(..))
val y = x.getMetaData()
```

can somebody shed some light on it?

I know lombok seems no problem with it after adding its **@Getter** annotation for example into Java source code, IntelliJ can recognize its getXXX method (which is generated by lombok).
I don't know how to implement the same for my case for kotlin language. please include the detailed steps if possible.

Comment: Are you using [Arrow Meta](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/meta/)? (just to confirm this is the library you meant with arrow-meta, I'm not familiar with it). If so, did you install the [Arrow Meta IntelliJ Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14291-arrow-meta)? It looks like this is their official plugin, though it is currently a little outdated and only works until IntelliJ 2020.1.4.

Comment: @Abby, Thanks! 
yes I am using Arrow Meta. however it seems no up-to-date IntelliJ plugin for it , hence I need to turn to other solution like the way Lombok did.

Lombok does annotations and then changes all java .class (synthetic), then IntelliJ can recognize all synthetic members and functions from .class files which added by Lombok.

now sure if anyone here met such problem before and had solutions already..  :(